# netbeans jbutton

Tags: image, user-interface, netbeans, jbutton

Does anyone know how to fit this image to jbutton? Any help would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GUI Builder:

1. Select the button
2. Right-click for properties.
3. Find the Icon property and click the "..." button next to it to select your file.

If you are hand-coding your GUI, just use the setIcon function of JButton.

eg:

```
jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("file://someicon.png")));
```

Comment: i already use the gui builder but it seems my icon cant fit http://i.stack.imgur.com/J7af2.png

Comment: Apparently I should have read more carefully.  Make sure the text of the button is set to the empty string and not a space or something. Drag a corner or edge of the button to resize. When it is the correct width a horizontal dotted line will appear across the button.